# Using enter key submitting more than one time

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a gallery with comment system. It means when I click on next and previous then the new pic with its comments are loaded. But the problem is that I am using a commentbox in which when I open a pic and submit comment for it, it submit the same comment only one time (the way it should work), but when I click on next pic (pic 2) and submit comment for it, the comment is submitted two times (instead of one), and the third pic three times and so on. Here is my jquery code  hope someone help me with this

```
$('body').on('keyup', '#stg_cmtarea', function(e) {

    if (e.which == 13 && $.trim(this.value).length) {
        var picId = $(".gal_cmt_cnt_info").attr('gdata');
        var userId = $("#mipicview-overlay-content").attr('vwid');
        var comment = $("#stg_cmtarea").val();
        var dataString = 'comment=' + comment + '&pic_id=' + picId + '&user_id=' + userId;
        if ($.trim(comment).length == 0) {
            alert("Please Enter Comment Text");
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "modules/gallery/piccomment_ajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    alert(html);

                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
});​
```

Comment: sure problem is not in your php code?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code.  It shoulds like you are rebinding the keyup event every time, and the event is just getting bound to the comment box too many times.

Comment: no php code is just fine , for a change i used a button to submit instead of enter key , using button its working fine but using enter key it is not

Comment: @ChrisThompson u did it damn i was so tensed that now it would take me hours to find where i was wrong u were right it was just getting bound to comment box too many times . can u please submit it as a answer so that i can aceept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with this code. It shoulds like you are rebinding the keyup event every time, and the event is just getting bound to the comment box too many times.

Answer (score 0):

Writing on my iPad, so it's not easy to test anything, but you could tyr this:

Change

```
$('body').on('keyup','#stg_cmtarea',
```

With

```
$('body').on('submit','#yourformid',
```

You should then remove the e.which-part. You could make a function that listens on enter if you really want submit on enter-push.

This should fix your problem. Remember to always return false, so the form is not submitted.